# Rails Trix editor throwing unexpected input field but not rendering expected (and rendered) field

Tags: css, trix

The following image illustrate the state of a form:
[image: console image of trix dialogs]

1. a first div with the `trix-toolbar` is injected, including a tag with name `href` that was automagically interpreted (nice to know) as having the requirement to be a URL, given it a placeholder and whatnot. Headscratcher: the field is rendered and **disabled**
2. the desired text area has its tag for `trix-editor` with a correct id

However that field is rendered as the tiny square seen at the top-left of the URL dialog div, with a 21x32 pixel dimension

the actiontext.css file is the gem generated one:

```
.trix-content .attachment-gallery > action-text-attachment,
.trix-content .attachment-gallery > .attachment {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  max-width: 33%;
}

.trix-content .attachment-gallery.attachment-gallery--2 > action-text-attachment,
.trix-content .attachment-gallery.attachment-gallery--2 > .attachment, .trix-content .attachment-gallery.attachment-gallery--4 > action-text-attachment,
.trix-content .attachment-gallery.attachment-gallery--4 > .attachment {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.trix-content action-text-attachment .attachment {
  padding: 0 !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Also note that the bases of the css are taken from zurb foundation implementing the XY grid, although that should not be of consequence as all the content is generated within a single div.

Adding:

```
.trix-content {
  display: block;
}
trix-toolbar{
  display: block;
}
trix-toolbar .trix-dialog--link {
  display: block;
}
```

does render the input block thoroughly, but still behind the url dialog box.

[image: input box full width but behind dialog box]

The `display: block;` instruction appears to be ignored.
[image: css for trix-dialog--link]

*still have not investigated what the impact of inputting a raw url does, so am uncertain as to whether this dialog is pertinent*

What should be done to ensure the trix-editor tag follows the trix-toolbar tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many sources of possible inheritance.  The resolution of above matter was to edit `stylesheets/actiontext.css` as follows, given the trix-dialog is set as a block display and adjust the editor based on its position relative to the URL dialog's height

```
trix-toolbar .trix-dialog {
  padding: 7px 5px;
  display: block;
}
trix-editor {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```